# Congruency by completing the square

Tags: congruences, chinese-remainder-theorem, completing-the-square

$x^2+x+1\equiv 0\mod 49$

We have the ring isomorphism $\mathbb{Z}/49\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}/7\mathbb{Z}$.

Consider $x^2+x+1\equiv 0\mod 7$

I usually solve these polynomial congruencies using the 'complete the square' method. How would I go about doing that in this case?

EDIT:

$x^2+x+1\equiv x^2-6x+8\equiv(x-3)^2\equiv 1\mod 7$

I get solutions $x=4$ and $x=2$ $\mod 7$.

Now I tried to use Hemel's lifting, so,

We have $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ thus $f'(x)=2x+1$.

In the case of $x\equiv 2\mod 7$, we have $f(2)=7$, $f'(2)=5$; as $7\nmid f'(2)$, we can lift to a unique solutions by solving $f'(2)\equiv -\frac{f(2)}{7}\mod 7$, i.e. $5t\equiv -1\mod 7$.

Clearly $t\equiv 4\mod 7$, leading to the solution $x\equiv 2+4\cdot 7\equiv 30\mod 49$.

In the case of $x\equiv 4\mod 7$, we have $f(4)=21$, $f'(4)=9$; as $7\nmid f'(4)$, we can lift to a unique solutions by solving $f'(4)t\equiv -\frac{f(4)}{7}\mod 7$ or $9t\equiv -\frac{9}{7}\mod 7$...and this is where I'm stuck, assuming I'm even doing it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mod 7, we have $$x^2+x+1\equiv x^2-6x+8=0$$ or $$(x-3)^2=1$$

Since $7$ is prime, each coprime number has either two square roots, or none.  Hence $x-3=1$ or $x-3=-1$, i.e. $x=4$ and $x=2$ are the two solutions mod $7$.

Comment: How did you get $x^2+x+1\equiv x^2-6x+8=0$?

Comment: $1\equiv -6, 1\equiv 8$

Comment: Are $x=4$ and $x=2$ all the solutions $\mod 49$?

Comment: @user3482534:  They are not solutions at all. One solution is $x\equiv 18\pmod{49}$.

Comment: To go from mod 7 to mod 49 you need the [lifting theorem](http://www.cs.xu.edu/math/math302/04f/PolyCongruences.pdf).

Comment: @vadim123 Could you check my edit in the OP please?

Answer (score 1):

**A start:** Equivalently, we solve $4x^2+4x+4\equiv 0\pmod{49}$, that is, $(2x+1)^2+3\equiv 0\pmod{49}$.

Comment: We end up with $(2x+1)^2\equiv 46\mod 49$, but 46 is not a square modulo 49...so does that complete the question?

Comment: I don't know how you are doing the calculation, maybe by Hensel lifting? The solutions of $y^2\equiv -3\pmod{7}$ are $y\equiv \pm 2$. Let us see whether the solution $y\equiv 2$ lifts. So we want $(2+7t)^2\equiv -3\pmod{49}$. That simplifies to $28t\equiv -7$, so to $4t\equiv -1\pmod{7}$. That gives $t=5$. So we should have $37^2\equiv -3\pmod{49}$. And indeed the square of $37$ is congruent to $46$. I don't know how you concluded $46$ was not a square mod $49$.